# I'm getting a "syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" error. I don't see what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

I'm getting this error:
"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/vhosts/... on line 66"

Here's my code:

```
function combine($charArr, $k) {

    $currentsize = sizeof($charArr);
    static $combs = array();
    static $originalsize = $currentsize; ###### <-- LINE 66 ######
    static $firstcall = true;

    if ($originalsize >= $k) {

        # Get the First Combination 
        $comb = '';
        if ($firstcall) { //if this is first call
            for ($i = $originalsize-$k; $i < $originalsize; $i++) {
                $comb .= $charArr[$i];
            }
            $combs[] = $comb; //append the first combo to the output array
            $firstcall = false; //we only want to do this during the first iteration
        }
    ....
    ....
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: why is $originalsize static if you overwrite it's value immediately on every function call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) *(that page is about static properties, but the same applies for variables)* :

> **Like any other PHP static variable, static** properties **may only be
> initialized using a literal or
> constant; expressions are not
> allowed**. So while you may initialize
> a static property to an integer or
> array (for instance), you may not
> initialize it to another variable, to
> a function return value, or to an
> object.

You are using this :

```
static $originalsize = $currentsize;
```

Which is initializing with an expression -- and not a constant.

And here's [the manual's section][2] that says quite the same about static variables :

> Static variables may be declared as
> seen in the examples above. Trying to
> assign values to these variables which
> are the result of expressions will
> cause a parse error.

And, just in case, here's [about expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).

In your case, to avoid that problem, I suppose you could modify your code, so it looks like this :

```
$currentsize = sizeof($charArr);
static $originalsize = null;
if ($originalsize === null) {
    $originalsize = $currentsize;
}
```

With that :

- The static variable is initialized with a constant
- If its value is the constant one, assign the dynamic value.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, excellent answer! You solution helps me retain the value of $originalsize from whatever it was set the first time the function was called. :)

Comment: That condition will return true on every test. Don't you think you should change static $originalsize = null; for static $originalsize;  and perhaps test the value of $currentsize instead?

Comment: dabito, $currentsize changes with each call of the function (it's recursive). $originalsize needs to be the same for always, starting with the first value it gets set to in that conditional statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
static $originalsize = $currentsize; ###### <-- LINE 66 ######
```

You can't pass a variable as the default value of a static variable. Instead, do the following:

```
static $originalsize;
$originalsize = $currentsize;
```

Comment: Great answer, but Pascal's was more informational. The best answer are both put together.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), **you may not initialize it to another variable**, to a function return value, or to an object.

Answer (score 0):

From [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.